# unittest Mock - how to set function variable value as return_value for patch

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to test following method under `my_module` module.

```
def function_to_test(inputs):
    foo = compute_foo(inputs) #Test this
    foo = store_and_return_foo()  # Do not test this
    do_work(foo)  # Test this
```

Is there a way to skip line 2 in test? (Assumption: `do_work` can give expected result regardless of if I use `foo` from line 1 or line 2. Line 2 is not just a side effect. that return value is useful in production but not in development/testing)

I can add a flag to method. eg. `function_to_test(inputs, store: bool)` but just wanted to see if there's a way to get around without adding it and still unittest it.

During test can I assign foo from line 1 to foo on line 2. something like `patch("my_module.get_complex_data_structure", return_value = 'my_module.function_to_test.foo')` .

Open to use any other mock library as well.

Comment: Why not use `store_foo` instead of `store_and_return_foo`? Then your mock return value can just be `None`

Comment: `store_and_return_foo` is needed. foo is a complex structure with metadata and data. once you store it, metadata gets updated. however for testing i can ignore those updated metadata but for non test env it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the method and use the value received as input as the return value using a side_effect. For example:

```py
@pytest.patch('my_module.store_and_return_foo')
def test_function_to_test(store_and_return_foo_mock: MagicMock):
   store_and_return_foo_mock.side_effect = lambda x: x
   inputs = ...
   foo = function_to_test(inputs)
   assert foo == ...
```

incase if you get an error `pytest has no module name patch` you can use `with patch` syntax:

```py
def test_function_to_test():
   with patch("my_module.store_and_return_foo") as my_mock:
     my_mock.side_effect = lambda x: x
     inputs = ...
     foo = function_to_test(inputs)
     assert foo == ...
```